# Multilanguages site PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, function, class

I have created several files in .php where inside there is an array that acts as a translator for the site.

This is the structure

```
/db/config.php
/lang/en/en.php
/lang/fr/fr.php
/lang/de/de.php
```

This is the en.php file

```
 <?php
      $lang = array(
           "one" => "one",
           "five" => "five",
           "nine" => "nine",
      );
 ?>
```

In the config file I have the database configuration and the insertion of the language array

File config.php

```
 <?php

 ...... DB Config .......
 $langServer = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

 if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']) && !isset($_GET['lang']){
      if($langServer == "en"){
           $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
      }else if($langServer == "fr"){
           $_SESSION['lang'] = "fr";
      }else if($langServer == "de"){
           $_SESSION['lang'] = "de";
      }else{
           $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
      }
 }else{
      $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
 }

 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lang/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . "/". $_SESSION['lang'] .".php");

 ?>
```

I wish I could access the array in some class or function, if I set a require_once it doesn't work...The only solution I found is to insert the array into a $ _SESSION but I don't like it as an idea..
That:
$_SESSION["arrayLang] = $lang;

I don't even want to have to require require_once on each function .... I wish I could access the $lang array anywhere ... any ideas? thank you

Comment: you can store a $lang variable in session which will set the required file. like if $lang = eng, require lang/en/en.php, if $lang = fr, require lang/fr/fr.php. dont forget about the default.

Answer (score 0):

if you require or include the config file in every file, you could use the define() function so you can read the "lang" global in every file.

In my example i also removed the ifelse statement because i think it is unnecessary, and it will make the application a tiny bit faster.

```
<?php

 ...... DB Config .......
 $langServer = substr($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'], 0, 2);

 require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/lang/" . $langServer . "/".$langServer .".php");

//define the global lang which can be used in every file this file will be included in
//you can use it without a $ just use the word "lang"
define('lang', $langServer);




 ?>
```